# Pass FILE* pointer from Swift to C Function

Tags: c, swift, file-pointer

I am using libxml in my iOS Swift project. To debug, I need to call the following C function from Swift:

```
void xmlDebugDumpString (FILE * output, const xmlChar * r)
```

However, I don't know how to create the `FILE * output` pointer in Swift.

I tried the following code:

```
let debugDoc: UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>
debugDoc = fopen(debugDocURL.absoluteString, "w")
xmlDebugDumpNode(debugDoc, str)
```

The code compiled fine but gives the following runtime error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the wrong usage of `absoluteString`, so that `fopen()`
fails and returns `nil`. The correct way to create a C string from an URL is `withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation`:

```
guard let debugFile = debugDocURL.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation( { fopen($0, "w") }) else {
    // Could not open file ...
}
```

Now you can write to the file

```
xmlDebugDumpNode(debugFile, ...)
```

and eventually close it:

```
fclose(debugFile)
```

An alternative option is to dump the debug output to the (predefined)
“standard error” file:

```
xmlDebugDumpNode(stderr, ...)
```